# if there is a production that contains a nonterminal nullable, then is that production nullable?

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, formal-languages

I was wondering, if I got a production that contains a nonterminal nullable, then is that production nullable?

A → aB | ε

B → bA | e

in this example, is B nullable because A is nullable?

Comment: May be it depends on how you declare production for nullable?

Answer (score 0):

`B` is nullable if and only if it has a nullable production. The production `B→bA` is not nullable because even if `A` derives the empty string, there is still a `b` in the derivation. The production `B→e` is clearly not nullable (unless `e` was a typo.) So `B` is not nullable.